# Grouping over the row values across multiple windows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, postgresql-8.4

Hi Basically I have the following table structure :
[image]

Now am trying to group them as following over the 13 week_end dates as below.

for example :  if we consider week_end as 11/17/2012 for the product p1, I should be able to sum up for prior 13 weeks rate and populate on 13week column on the table (that is sum of rate from row 16 through 29th row ). I tried to write function as below but was not successful because of the error "accessing relationship"

```
create or replace function vin_last_13week_rate(j date,p_name text) RETURNS numeric AS $$
declare
week_end date;
rate_tot numeric;
rate_tot_final numeric default 0;
current_week date;
i integer;

begin
week_end:=(j::date - CAST(EXTRACT(DOW FROM j::date)+1 as int))::timestamp +'1 week'::interval+'23 hours'::interval+'59 minutes'::interval+'59 seconds'::interval ;

for i in 1..13 loop
current_week :=week_end - 7;
select total_rate into rate_tot from res where week_end = current_week and product_name = p_name ;

rate_tot_final= rate_tot_final + rate_tot;

end loop;
return rate_tot_final;

end

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

select vin_last_13week_rate(week_end,product_name) from res;
```

I get the error : function cannot execute on segment because it accesses relation "res"
Could some one help me out doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how the final answer exactly should look like? In other words, what do you exactly mean by "like wise for the all the dates across week,13 week , 52 for all the products"?

Comment: @DanielSparing edited my post to explain it clearly now. Could you please have a look now

Comment: alright, to begin with, you already read res from the function body so no need to read also when calling, can you try the following and post the error: `select vin_last_13week_rate(week_end,product_name);`

Comment: yes it gives me the result, but my point is that the results should be present along with the data thats the reason am using 'from res' here

Comment: well your result is a number and your table is a table. How would you like to combine them? A new column containing the same value in every row? That is `SELECT *, (SELECT vin_last_13week_rate(week_end,product_name)) rate_tot FROM res`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need a `group by`.
Please try this:

```
SELECT product_name, week_start, sum(week_rate)
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY product_name, week_start
ORDER BY product_name, week_start
```

Comment: Edited my post now . COuld you please have a look now